# Choosing the smallest number in a matrix except for those on the main diagonal line

Tags: r

I'm trying to identify the similarity of words contained in column A and produced a matrix using the adist function. I want to choose the words with the shortest distance except on the diagonal line. Therefore, I applied a function that would identifies the second-to-smallest number, but it sometimes include the 0 on the diagonal line, because all numbers on the main diagonal of the matrix is 0 by definition. I want to get the smallest number except for the one on the main diagonal.

```
a1 = df['A']
a2 = df['A']
dist.name <- adist(a1$A, a2$A, partial = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
min.name <- apply(dist.name, 1, function(x)(sort(x)[2]))
```

Below is an example of the dist.name matrix.

```
    a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
a1  0   3   0   3   1
a2  1   0   3   5   0
a3  2   3   0   0   5
a4  3   0   1   0   5
a5  0   3   2   1   0
```

I want to be able to choose [a1, a3] rather than [a1, a1].

Comment: I think I can do it but I don't have any `df`

Comment: `which.min(\`diag<-\`(m, Inf))`? (Not tested since the example is not easy to copy-paste and desired output is not clear)

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `mat` is your data.frame:

```
> mat2 <- as.matrix(mat)
> diag(mat2) <- NA
```

Alternative 1

```
  > apply(mat2, 1, min, na.rm=TRUE) 
    a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 
     0  0  0  0  0
```

Alternative 2

```
> which(mat2==min(mat2, na.rm = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)
   row col
a5   5   1
a4   4   2
a1   1   3
a3   3   4
a2   2   5
```

Answer (score 1):

Lacking any copy of df or even a clear description of it this is a guess. The code:

```
 !diag(dim(dist.name)[1] )
```

... creates a logical square matrix of same dimensions as `dist.name` and when used as an index selects the non-diagonal elements, thusly:

```
 min.name <- min( dist.name[!diag(dim(dist.name)[1] )]
```

After rebuilding a copy of the dist.name matrix we see that it still finds all the 0's that were in the off-diagonal elements. So I perhaps odidn't I understand the goal, but negating diag(5) does remove all the diagonal zeroes:

```
dist.name <- matrix( scan(text="
   0   3   0   3   1
   1   0   3   5   0
   2   3   0   0   5
   3   0   1   0   5
   0   3   2   1   0"), 5,5,byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(c(    'a1',  'a2',  'a3',  'a4',  'a5'), c(    'a1',  'a2',  'a3',  'a4',  'a5')) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A description of df is not important in this context. What's important is the dist.name matrix.

Comment: OK. I think this is correct to that goal then. And it is a more "viRtuous" answer in the sense of using all vectorized function (no `apply`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the smallest number of a matrix (or df) not on the diagonal, you can always do this by insuring that the min value isn't on the diagonal.  One way to do this is- 
df2 = df + diag(max(df)+1,nrow(df),ncol(df) ). Then min(df2) will not be on the diagonal.